# DHCP assign IP address based on MAC address with Cisco CE 500 platform?

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, dhcp

I have very little knowledge about CISCO and its switches, but now I have to configure it myself.

Is it possible to allot IP address based on MAC address on CISCO CE 500 (Cisco Catalyst Express 500-24TT Switch [**WS-CE500-24TT**] )switches ?

Comment: You're referring to a general feature known as "DHCP Reservation"

Comment: @Yosef, is it possible to do that on CE 500 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it possible to allot IP address based on MAC address on CISCO CE 500

No you need a real Cisco IOS switch for [DHCP server functionality with Maunal Bindings](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2/ip/configuration/guide/1cfdhcp.html#wp1001108); the Catalyst Express series switches do not run IOS

Answer (score 7):

If all you want to do is permanently assign IPs to certain MAC addresses, this is simple. It's called a **permanent DHCP lease**. You need do this on the network's DHCP server. While the Cisco Catalyst Express 500 series switches can serve up DHCP, I don't know about advanced DHCP options; and if this is any kind of real network you wouldn't want a switch as your DHCP server.

You can find the [official documentation on configuring CE 500s here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6545/products_configuration_example09186a00806da6c9.shtml). If the switch doesn't support permanent DHCP leases, then you can always assign the computer's addresses statically from its internal network configuration (`/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian based Linux distros). Hopefully that documentation helps you get to where you're going.

Answer (score 5):

I know this isn't specifically on topic - however I believe its worth mentioning that IPv6 actually has the ability to assign an IP address based on the MAC address by using eui-64 notation.

This also does not require a DHCPv6 server as it is stateless.

Please see the following links for more information (1st 2 google results, how original)
http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/aug/4/eui-64-ipv6/
https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-24485